# convert the complex XML to CSV file

Tags: xml, csv, converters

When I tried to Convert the below format complex XML into CSV file through some online tools it's providing multiple csv files? Is that only way to have all the below XML elements and it's attributes to be converted into multiple CSV? or Is that any way to create one csv file with all the below elements and attributes in the xml?

*SAMPLE XML:*

```
<messages>
<message messageID="12345" orderNumber="1111111" model="AA" tls="22222" status="99" timestamp="2014-04-25 08:27:17Z">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="aaaaaaaaaa" value="ff" />
        <attribute name="bbbbbbbb" value="L.f" />
        <attribute name="ccccccccc" value="333" />
        <attribute name="ddddddddd" value="n.998" />
    </attributes>
</message>
<message messageID="12345" orderNumber="1111111" model="AA" tls="22222" status="99" timestamp="2014-04-25 08:27:17Z">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="yyyyyyy" value="j8" />
        <attribute name="jjjjjjjjjj" value="L.O" />
        <attribute name="mmmmmmm" value="33333" />
        <attribute name="nnnnnnnn" value="K.9999" />
    </attributes>
</message>
</messages>
```

Answer (score 0):

XML looks like the appropriate format since it is nested data. You could also use JSON or YAML. The only chance to put the data into a single CSV file, is to flatten the `<attributes>` into a string like this:

```
(aaaaaaaaaa;ff)(bbbbbbbb;L.f)...
```

However this will only work unless your data does not contain the `()` and `;` - or unless you find some other valid delimiters for that.

Then the CSV could look like:

```
messageID,orderNumber, ... ,attributes
12345,1111111, ... ,(aaaaaaaaaa;ff)(bbbbbbbb;L.f)...
```

But this is hack and a common CSV parser will not understand that. However, if you have control about the CSV writer and parser on the other site you could use it. But then, why don't you just use XML (or JSON, YAML)?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. any It is good to convert into JSON format, but I need to check the downstream system whether they support JSON. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try : 
http://www.deeppay.net/sepa/sepa2csv.html

It does the flattening for you. The attribute names and values will be in different columns through :

```
"type",".../@timestamp",".../@status",".../message/@tls",".../@model",".../@orderNumber",".../@messageID",".../attribute[3]/type",".../attribute[3]/$",".../attribute[3]/.../@value",".../attribute[3]/.../@name",".../attribute[2]/type",".../attribute[2]/$",".../attribute[2]/.../@value",".../attribute[2]/.../@name",".../attribute[1]/type",".../attribute[1]/$",".../attribute[1]/.../@value",".../attribute[1]/.../@name",".../attribute[0]/type",".../attribute[0]/$",".../attribute[0]/.../@value",".../attribute[0]/.../@name"
"/messages/message","2014-04-25 08:27:17Z","99","22222","AA","1111111","12345","/messages/message/attributes/attribute","","n.998","ddddddddd","/messages/message/attributes/attribute","","333","ccccccccc","/messages/message/attributes/attribute","","L.f","bbbbbbbb","/messages/message/attributes/attribute","","ff","aaaaaaaaaa"
"/messages/message","2014-04-25 08:27:17Z","99","22222","AA","1111111","12345","/messages/message/attributes/attribute","","K.9999","nnnnnnnn","/messages/message/attributes/attribute","","33333","mmmmmmm","/messages/message/attributes/attribute","","L.O","jjjjjjjjjj","/messages/message/attributes/attribute","","j8","yyyyyyy"
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this app from windows store:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/xml-into-csv/9p0qsrvjcsj5

It's capable to normalize whole xml into flat-table structure:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try: [XML to CSV converter](https://conversiontools.io/convert/xml-to-csv) at [conversiontools.io](https://conversiontools.io)

It is not only combines data based on the XML tags, but also taking into account attribute names.
Also, it support large XML files up to 20 Gb.

[image: conversion xml to csv]